# url not opening in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I call the following javascript functions to open/create an iframe whenever createRemoteSampleWindow() is called. The problem is that the menu that I have scripted after DB in title, onChange opens the links in a new window rather than opening in the same iframe itself.

```
function changeSpecies(selector){
var selected = document.getElementsByName(selector)[0].value;
var new_url = window.location.toString().replace(selected);
window.location.href = new_url;
}

function createRemoteSampleWindow() { // create a iframe window
var sampleWnd = $.window({
    url: "http://www.google.com",       
    title: 'DB <select id="click" OnChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value')" name="selector" target="sampleWnd"> <option value="http://www.goal.com" selected="">human</option> <option value="http://www.mirror.co.uk">mouse</option> <option value="http://www.espnstar.com">rat</option> </select>',
});
```

I have mentioned target="sampleWnd", but this doesnt seem to work.

Kindly tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have a `'` after value, where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I forgot to add the backslashes here for the inverted commas. So, following is the new updated code-
    title: "DB <select id=\"click\" OnChange=\"window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value')\" name=\"selector\" target=\"sampleWnd\"> <option value=\"http://www.goal.com\" selected="">human</option> <option value=\"http://www.mirror.co.uk\">mouse</option> <option value=\"http://www.espnstar.com\">rat</option> </select>",
but this doesnt work. Replacing "double inv commas at the start & end after title: with ' -at least shows the dropdown menu in the menu bar of the dialog box.

Comment: The only problem that is coming here is that OnChange of the menu option, the links - espnstar, goal.com..- are opening in a new window rather than in the iframe itself, inspite of specifying - OnChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value')" - which seems to be correct. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax not withstanding; Google actively blocks a browser from opening it in an IFrame.
It's for security (and stopping people hijacking googles content!)

This link has some info but basically it's a massive pain to work around and Google don't want you to do it anyway so you might run the risk of getting your account blocked.

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=242978

Comment: Thank you PitaJ, Russ for your comments.

Comment: The link opens in a new window from the iframe dropdown menu. I want the exact same thing which happens [here] (http://biogps.org/#goto=genereport&id=1017). - In the species dropdown menu at the top of the iframe dialog box, the frame reloads.